# Python with grep/sed/awk command

Tags: python

I am new to `Python` and trying to figure out how to get the port number from `/etc/services` if I give the port name.

`/etc/services` contains following value

```
DB2_test    60000/tcp
DB2_test_1  60001/tcp
DB2_test_2  60002/tcp
DB2_test_3  60003/tcp
DB2_test_4  60004/tcp
DB2_test_END    60005/tcp
```

The command

```
db2port=os.popen("db2 get dbm cfg | grep -i Service | awk '{{print $6}}'").read()
print(db2port)
```

returns `DB2_test`

The below command does not work. I want to just see the value of DB2_test, which is 60000:

```
getnum = "cat /etc/services | sed -n '/\{db2port}\s/p' | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/\/tcp$//'"
print(getnum}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to invoke awk, sed etc. A pure Python solution would be:

```
for line in open("/etc/services").readlines():
        parts = line.split()

        if parts and parts[0] == 'DB2_test':
                port, protocol = parts[1].split('/')
                print(port)
```

Comment: hmm, getting following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t1", line 12, in <module>
    if parts[0] == 'DB2_test':
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I've added a check to see if `parts` contain anything at all before accessing parts[0]. This can happen with empty lines.

Comment: I did a print(parts) just after parts=line.split() I can see data on screen. But it seems the if statement does not work.

Comment: The added check handles any result where `line.split()` returns an empty list (if the line is empty), so add that check and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the variable `services` contains the text from your `/etc/services`.

```
port_map = {
    name: int(value.split('/')[0])
    for name, value in (
        line.split() for line in services.splitlines()
    )
}
```

Now you have a map from the service's name to its port, so that `port_map["DB2_test"] == 60000`, for example.